# Can't launch system monitor under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu Karmic (fresh install from disc), I haven't been able to launch the system monitor. Nothing happens if I launch it via the Applications menu on the top. If I try to launch it via the terminal, I get this output:

```
sirupsen@puter:~$ gnome-system-monitor

** (gnome-system-monitor:13845): WARNING **: SELinux was found but is not enabled.


GLib-GObject-ERROR **: Attempt to add property GtkMenuBar::local to class after it was derived
aborting...
Aborted
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I could do to fix this, so I would be able to use the system monitor again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1289649

You can try changing the theme and (if enabled) disabling the global menu bar.

Comment: Woah! It worked to diable the global menu. :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Good. Let's hope this gets fixed as soon as possible.